# nslookup - return only the IP address of host

Tags: linux, nslookup

I'd like to be able to return only the IP from a nslookup command. Currently if I execute:

```
>nslookup foo21.bar.local
```

it will return something like:

```
Server:     11.13.5.134
Address:    11.13.5.134#53

Name:   foo21.bar.local
Address: 11.13.35.312
```

I would like a command that returns just the:

```
11.13.35.312
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dig` has options to make that easy:

```
 dig +short foo21.bar.local
```

will just give you the A records, one per line (a domain can have more than one A record). To only get the first one:

```
 dig +short foo21.bar.local | head -n1
```

Comment: thanks Marcus. That works. I guess dig is in all of our environments but not sure? I guess I was think of something using sed / grep /awk

Answer (score 5):

Using `dig` as [@Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71483492/5625547) suggest is the most clean way.

---

To answer your question, we can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to get only the line with `Address` and then get the second col:

```
nslookup google.com | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }'
```

Will output:

```
216.58.208.110
```